# How to store data from two arrays to one hashmap as keyvalue pair with some filters

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have two arrays, first array is a 1d array and second is 2d array.

Array 1:

```
1,2,3,4,5..
```

Array2:

```
open 1 2 2d 3 4 close
open 4 5 close
```

At the end I want a HashMap which should be

```
1-open, 1, 2, 2d,3,4,close
2-open,4,5,close
```

where 1 is the key followed by values

Code which I have tried for my program to get the result

```
//converting list to two dimentional array
String[][] stringArray = new String[EventAll.size()][];
int flag=0;
int u = 0;
for (List<Object> event : EventAll) {
    stringArray[u++] = event.toArray(new String[event.size()]);
    System.out.println(event.size());
    //iterating thought 1st array
    for (int i = 0; i < workFlowData.size(); i++){
        //iterating through 2d array
        for ( int row1 = 0; row1 <=stringArray.length ; row1++) {
            for(int column1=0; column1<=stringArray[row1].length;column1++){
                /*stringArray[row1][column1] =row1 * column1;*/
                //checking herar for open projects
                if (stringArray[row1][column1].contains("Open Project")) {
                    flag = 1;
                    System.out.println(flag);
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                        System.out.println("map:"+map.size());

                        map.put(workFlowData.get(i), stringArray.length);
                        flag=0;
                        for (int ss = 0; ss < map.size(); ss++) {
                            System.out.println(map.get(i));
                            System.out.println("map:"+map);
                            if(stringArray[row1][column1].contains("Close Project"))
                            {
                                break;
                            }           
                        }
                    } else{
                        flag=0;
                        System.out.println(flag);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

sample data[image]

Comment: What is the 1D array used for here? Is open and close the start and end of the 2D array column/row?

Comment: open,1,2
g,1,2
r,1,2
close,1,2
open,2,3
e,4,5
close,2,3 .. so this is a sample array2 data shown, i want to put each value of array1 linked to above data between open and close events. Thanks

Comment: Attached a sample data .please check

Comment: Can you also post the required output in a table format.. Now it is really confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your 1D array is

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

And your 2D array is

```
open,1,2,3,close
open,4,5,6,close
```

And the expected output is

```
1 - open,1,2,3,close
2 - open,4,5,6,close
```

Below code should work

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
String[][] array2 = { { "open", "1", "2", "close" }, { "open", "3", "4", "close" } };
HashMap<Integer, List> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int firstArray = 0; firstArray < array2.length; firstArray++ ) {
    String[] temp2DRow = array2[firstArray];
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (temp2DRow[0].contains("open")) {
        for (String str : temp2DRow) {
            list.add(str);
        }
    }
    map.put(array1[firstArray], list);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: {open,1,2}
{g,1,2}
{r,1,2}
{close,1,2}
{open,2,3}
{e,4,5}
{close,2,3} and whenever open appears  upto close should be mapped to 1st data of the 1d array

Comment: Output should be 1->open,1,2;g,1,2;r,1,2;close,1,2
2->open,2,3;e,4,5;close,2,3